# Concatenating a list of files with subprocess and wildcards in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to concatenate multiple files in a directory to a single file. So far I've been trying to use cat with subprocess with poor results.

My original code was:

```
source = ['folder01/*', 'folder02/*']
target = ['/output/File1', '/output/File2']

for f1, f2, in zip(source, target):
    subprocess.call(['cat', f1, '>>', f2])
```

I've tried handing it shell=True:

```
..., f2], shell=True)
```

And in conjunction with subprocess.Popen instead of call in a number of permutations, but with no joy.

As I've understood from other similar questions,  with shell=True the command will need to be provided as a string. How can I go about calling cat on all items in my list whilst executing as a string?

Comment: You would do `string = "cat {} >> {}".format(f1, f2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `subprocess` here and you must always avoid `subprocess` when you can (that means: 99.99% of time).

As [Joel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1142167/joel-cornett) pointed out in comments, maybe I should take a few minutes and bullet points to explain you why:

1. Using `subprocess` (or similar) assume your code will always run on the exact same environment, that means same OS, version, shell, tools installed, etc.. This is really not fitted for a production grade code.
2. These kind of libraries will prevent you to make "pythonic Python code", you will have to handle errors by parsing string instead of `try` / `except`, etc..
3. Tim Peters wrote the Zen of Python and I encourage you to follow it, at least 3 points are relevant here: "*Beautiful is better than ugly.*", "*Readability counts.*" and "*Simple is better than complex.*".

In other words: `subprocess` will only make your code less robust, force you to handle non-Python issues, force you to perform tricky computing where you could just write clean and powerful Python code.

There are way more good reasons to not use `subprocess`, but I think you got the point.

---

Just open files with `open`, here is a basic example you will need to adapt:

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir('./'):
    with open(filename, 'r') as fileh:
        with open('output.txt', 'a') as outputh:
            outputh.write(fileh.read())
```

---

Implementation example for your specific needs:

```
import os

sources = ['/tmp/folder01/', '/tmp/folder02/']
targets = ['/tmp/output/File1', '/tmp/output/File2']

# Loop in `sources`
for index, directory in enumerate(sources):
    # Match `sources` file with expected `targets` directory
    output_file = targets[index]
    # Loop in files within `directory`
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        # Compute absolute path of file
        filepath = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        # Open source file in read mode
        with open(filepath, 'r') as fileh:
            # Open output file in append mode
            with open(output_file, 'a') as outputh:
                # Write content into output
                outputh.write(fileh.read())
```

*Be careful, I changed your source and target values (`/tmp/`)*

Comment: Gave you some help here :)

Comment: Been trying to integrate this solution. So far I have:

    `for f1, f2 in in zip(source, target):

        for filename in os.listdir(f1):

            with open(filename, 'r') as fileh:

                with open(f2, 'a') as outputh:

                    outputh.write(fileh.read())`

Which seems like it would be working, but it's looking for the files in the wrong place. I've not used os.listdir before - how can I get it to write the full path to the list instead of just file names?

Nevermind, you anticipated my question and beat me to it! Thank you so much.

Comment: :), you can use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) too, but I prefer `os.listdir()`. I may be wrong on that specific point, so takes some docs and make your choice.

Comment: Really clear and concise answer. Integrated the solution perfectly, thank you!

Comment: I upvoted, but disagree with the statement “you must always avoid subprocess whenever you can”. It’s not that I disagree with the sentiment, but that fact you’re making a blanket statement without any qualifications. Please state *why* you shouldn’t reach for subprocess so often.

Comment: @JoelCornett "_long life to Joel_" https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48867114/revisions

Comment: I was actually really curious about not using subprocess and was trying to read up on why, really appreciate that edit! My current use case is creating a script to automate a lengthly analysis pipeline usually executed from bash. It uses a multiple programs by other people - all I'm really doing is naming and moving files to hand to the *real* programs! I see that Popen is recommended over call for security, but as I need to wait for a successful sys completion it seems like call is the right one to use.

Comment: Well in your specific case I would go with Bash. I understand if you are not familiar with Bash this may be scary, Bash is really not easy to learn, especially for somebody without strong scripting / development skills. But anyway, from what I understood, Bash is what you really want.